# How can I show that sample mean has the smallest variance?

Tags: statistics, estimation

Let the population distribution is $N(\mu,1)$.
Sample mean: $\bar{X_n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i}{n}$
Then $E(\bar{X_n})=\mu$ and $V(\bar{X_n})=\frac{1}{n}$
It is an unbiased estimator, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$ it converges to $\mu$.
But I want to show that it is the minimun variance estimator, for example,
take another unbiased estimator $Y_n$ and show $V(\bar{X_n}) \le V(Y_n)$.

Comment: You can show that the sample mean is a complete, sufficient statistic for the estimation of $\mu$. The Lehmann-Scheffe theorem than states that it is the MVUE estimator of $\mu$. If you need further assistance, try pointing out what have you already tried.

Comment: @SBM I use MSE convergence and show that smaple mean is a consistent estimator. Is it not sufficient for this proof?

Comment: Well, consistency is an asymptotic property, which has nothing to do with MVUE (Infact, being an MVU estimator doesn't imply consistency). Have you heard of the cramer-rao bound or Lehmann Scheffe theorem?

Comment: @SBM Yes, I studied that. Actually, the question is to show that sample mean is a "good estimator of $\mu$" and I wonder what "good estimator" means... So I just tried to show that sample mean has the minimum variance.

Comment: If you learned about the CRB, than I guess a good estimator is an efficient one (Though I'm guessing), This means that this estimator is unbiased, MVU and attains the cramer rao bound for both the small and large sample sizes.

Comment: @SBM Okay, I'll try to show it is the UMCLU(we use this term in class)!

Comment: @SBM : Actually, the proof of completeness might not be trivial in this case.

Comment: @Michael Hardy As much as I recall, it is quite easy using a fourier transform, but I might be confused:-)

Comment: @Michael Hardy Oops, I didn't noticed you proved it the way I recalled :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to show only that the sample mean has a smaller variance than every other weighted average of the observations, then this would be an exercise in Lagrange multipliers.  But if you want to include *all* unbiased estimators of $\mu$ based on $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ (for example, the sample median is one such estimator, and is not a weighted average of the observations), then this becomes equivalent to the one-to-one nature of the two-sided Laplace transform.

Observe that the **conditional** distribution of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ **given** $\bar X = (X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ does not depend on $\mu$.  (I could add the details of how to find the conditional distribution if necessary.)  In other words, the sample mean $\bar X$ is a [sufficient statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufficient_statistic) for $\mu$.  Therefore, the [Rao–Blackwell theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rao%E2%80%93Blackwell_theorem) tells us that any minimum-variance estimator is to be found only among functions of $\bar X$.

Therefore it is enough to show that the only function $g(\bar X)$ of $\bar X$ (where of course, which function $g$ is, is not allowed to depend on $\mu$; i.e. $g(\bar X)$ is actually a statistic) that is an unbiased estimator of $\mu$ is $\bar X$ itself.

The density function of $\bar X$ is
$$
x\mapsto \text{constant}\cdot \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{x-\mu}{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right).
$$
In order that the function $g(\bar X)$ be an unbiased estimator of $\mu$, we must $g(\bar X)-\bar X$ being an unbiased estimator of $0$.  Let $h(x) = g(x)-x$; then we must have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\text{same constant})\cdot h(x) \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2}\cdot\left(\frac{x-\mu}{1/\sqrt{n}}\right)^2\right) \, dx = 0
$$
for all values of $\mu$.  Hence
$$
\text{same constant}\cdot \exp\left(\frac{-n\mu^2}{2}\right) \cdot \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(h(x) \exp\left(\frac{-n}{2} x^2\right)\right) \exp\left(nx\mu\right) \, dx = 0
$$
regardless of the value of $\mu$.  Thus the two-sided Laplace transform of the function
$$
x\mapsto h(x)\exp\left( \frac{-nx^2}{2} \right)
$$
is $0$ for all values of $\mu$.

Since the two-sided Laplace transform is one-to-one, it can map only one function to the identically zero function.